# Daterange + top_hits aggregation (as subaggregation) with Elasticsearch Java API Client 7.17.x

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-java-api

I've been at this for a day and I don't quite understand how I do it! This is the query I want to "recreate" with the new Java API Client (using Spring Boot)

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          { "to": "now-2d" } 
        ]
      }
    }
  ,
  "aggs": {
      "top_hits": {
        "_source": {
              "includes": [ "Id", "timestamp" ]
            }
      }
  }
}
}
```

I tried doing it with `DateRangeAggregation.of` but I can't seem to get the right results or type. Here's what I have

```java
SearchResponse<MyDto> response = client.search(b -> b
                .index("test-index")
                .size(0) 
                .aggregations("range",a->a.dateRange(DateRangeAggregation.of(d->d
                  .field("timestamp").ranges(r->r.to(t->t.expr("now-2d")))))),
                    .aggregations("hits", a -> a
                        .topHits(h->h.source(SourceConfig.of(c->c.filter(f->f.includes(Arrays.asList("Id", "timestamp"))))))),
                MyDto.class 
            );
```

I've also tried removing the `subaggregation` and query for now, but I don't seem to be on the right track to even get the number of `doc_count` from the bucket. I kind of don't get how to work with the `dateRange()` here.

Edit: I played around a bit and was able to at least get the number of `doc_count`, I'm not very sure if this is a good way to do it though?

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.of(a -> a
            .dateRange(d->d.field("timestamp").ranges(r->r.to(FieldDateMath.of(v->v.expr("now-2d"))))));
        
SearchResponse<MyDto> response = client.search(b -> b
               .index("test-index")
               .size(0) 
               .aggregations("range", agg),
                MyDto.class 
            );

return response.aggregations().get("range").dateRange().buckets().array().get(0).docCount();
```

I also fixed the query above, it had an unnecessary extra query that broke the result.

Answer (score 0):

My thought process was wrong. I wanted the documents that were aggregated within this a time but I misunderstood and thought tophits would give them to me, but that's not how it works! I made a seperate range query that actually queries the documents I needed back instead.